# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoChart is not a function what should i do

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to use the chart component in kendoui, but I encountered the following problem in the process of using it, the problem prompted me $(...).kendoChart is not a function. I have introduced the required js, I want to know what I should do, here is my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="${base.contextPath}/lib/kendoui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${base.contextPath}/lib/kendoui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>

</style>
    <div class="row" id="exmple">
        <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        var data = [
            {
                "source": "Hydro",
                "percentage": 22,
                "explode": true
            },
            {
                "source": "Solar",
                "percentage": 2
            },
            {
                "source": "Nuclear",
                "percentage": 49
            },
            {
                "source": "Wind",
                "percentage": 27
            }
        ];

        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Break-up of Spain Electricity Production for 2008"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                dataSource: {
                    data: data
                },
                series: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    field: "percentage",
                    categoryField: "source",
                    explodeField: "explode"
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#03a9f4", "#ff9800", "#fad84a", "#4caf50"]
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</body>
```

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoChart is not a function

Comment: Have you checked whether that library really got loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a missing kendo library (kendo.dataviz.min.js) essential for the chart. This file doesn't seem to be available unless the product is  bought as described in this forum post:

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the post ?